# Creating a local Ubuntu repository on Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I am trying to create a local Ubuntu repository on a Docker container based on Ubuntu 16.04 xenial. I followed this tutorial:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal

Here the steps executed as root user:

```
1. mkdir -p /root/repo/amd_64
2. copied all debian packages in /root/repo/amd_64
3. create the script /usr/bin/update-mydebs.sh with the following content:
#! /bin/bash
cd /root/repo/amd_64
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
4. Run the script update-mydebs.sh (I verified the Packages.gz is 
correctly created under /root/repo/amd_64)
5. Added the line in /etc/apt/source.list
deb file:/root/repo amd_64/
```

When I run apt-get update I got the following problem:

```
Get:1 file:/root/repo amd_64/ InRelease
Ign:1 file:/root/repo amd_64/ InRelease
Get:2 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Release
Ign:2 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Release
Get:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages [54.3 kB]
Ign:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Get:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Ign:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Get:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Ign:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Get:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Ign:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Get:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Ign:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Get:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
Err:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
File not found - /root/repo/amd_64/Packages (2: No such file or 
directory)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file 
'/root/repo/amd_64/InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - 
pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
W: The repository 'file:/root/repo amd_64/ Release' does not have a 
Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch file:/root/repo/amd_64/Packages  File not found - 
/root/repo/amd_64/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
```

tried to fix the issue simply unzipping the /root/repo/amd_64/Packages.gz in /root/repo/amd_64/Packages, the problem of file not found is solved but another error occurred:

```
Get:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages [169 kB]
Err:3 file:/root/repo amd_64/ Packages
    Could not open file 
    /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_root_repo_amd%5f64_Packages - open 
    (13: Permission denied)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file 
'/root/repo/amd_64/InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - 
pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
W: The repository 'file:/root/repo amd_64/ Release' does not have a 
Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore 
potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user c 
configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch 
store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_root_repo_amd%5f64_Packages  Could 
not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_root_repo_amd%5f64_Packages 
- open (13: Permission denied)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old 
ones used instead.
```

I noticed that all tutorials on the web about this subject are similar to the one I linked so I suppose it is correct, but probably there is something that must be changed when we apply the procedure on Docker container.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you have a `Dockerfile` you can share, so other people can try to reproduce your issue?  Is the `/root/repo` directory baked into the image, a bind-mounted host directory, or something else?  It looks like you're getting pretty clear error messages and so a reproduction that fixed the permission errors would be helpful too.

Comment: The Dockerfile is something like this:
    FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget git xz-utils openssh-server \
 systemd-services libsensors4 gcc
ENTRYPOINT service ssh start && /bin/bash
EXPOSE 22

Comment: When I start the container I have only /root, the root/repo is created manually. No bind mount on these folders.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well.  Took me a LOT of searching to find:
https://github.com/radeno/polyfill-service-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile

with the note:

```
# work around the following APT issue by using "Acquire::GzipIndexes=false" (overriding "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes")
#   Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_tmp_tmp.ODWljpQfkE_._Packages - open (13: Permission denied)
#   ...
#   E: Failed to fetch store:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_tmp_tmp.ODWljpQfkE_._Packages  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/_tmp_tmp.ODWljpQfkE_._Packages - open (13: Permission denied)
```

After adding as part of the update command, this worked as expected for a local repository.